# Ctrl + C: does it kill threads too along with main process?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

While running a thread program and repeatedly killing the main program using `Ctrl + C`, i see unexpected results in the program in second run. However, if i let the program run and voluntarily exit, there are no issues.

So, my doubt is, does `Ctrl + C`, kill threads also along with the main process?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the only thing that `Ctrl + C` does is sending `SIGINT` to *one* thread in the process that is not masking the signal. Signals can be handled or ignored.

If the program *does* handle `Ctrl+C`, the usual behavior is self-termination, but once again, it could be used for anything else.

In your case, `SIGINT` is being received by *one* thread, which probably does kill itself, but does not kill the others.

Comment: @Heandel: Any key combination you know to kill the process + threads?

Comment: @Heandel: That i know, and in fact i think all Linux users :) I was interested to know key combinations.

Comment: @Heandel: Thank You, do u have any web links corresponding to this? If yes, it will be very useful not only for me but for all users.

Comment: @kingsmasher - `stty -a` will tell you that Ctrl-C sends SIGINT and Ctrl-\ sends SIGQUIT ('intr = ^C; quit=^\').  `man 7 signal` to see a little about what individual signals mean.

Comment: @fizzer: Really useful piece of info. Thanks.

Comment: Note that a process could handle SIGQUIT and misbehave.  There is no 'key combination' to generate SIGKILL (stty's kill=^U means something else - see `man stty`).  So, the only 'reliable' way to kill a process from the terminal is `kill -9`.

Comment: Scare quotes round 'reliable' because even `kill -9` fails in rare circumstances.

Comment: Note that the *default* action for `SIGINT` is to terminate the entire process, not just one thread.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. As caf pointed out, the default action for `SIGINT` is to kill the process. There is **no such thing** as killing one thread. If any thread receives a signal for which the action is to kill the process, then the whole process dies. If you don't want this, you can install a handler for the signal (except for `SIGKILL`).

Comment: If a thread receives `SIGINT` and calls `_exit` from the signal handler, the whole process will terminate. If the thread calls `pthread_exit` from the signal handler, it's invoked UB unless it can be sure no async-signal-unsafe function was interrupted by the signal.

Answer (score 6):

In multithreaded programming, signals are delivered to a single thread (usually chosen unpredictably among the threads that don't have that particular signal blocked). However, this **does not mean** that a signal whose default action is to kill the process only terminates one thread. In fact, **there is no way** to kill a single thread without killing the whole process.

As long as you leave `SIGINT` with its default action of terminating the process, it will do so as long as at least one thread leaves `SIGINT` unblocked. It doesn't matter which thread has it unblocked as long as at least one does, so library code creating threads behind the application's back should always block all signals before calling `pthread_create` and restore the signal mask in the calling thread afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux 2.6 using NPTL threads: I am assuming that the process uses the default signal handler, or calls exit() in it: Yes it does. The C library exit() call maps to the exit_group system call which exits all the threads immediately; the default signal handler calls this or something similar.

Under Linux 2.4 using Linuxthreads (or using 2.6 if your app still uses Linuxthreads for some weird reason): Not necessarily.

The Linuxthreads library implements threads using clone(), creating a new process which happens to share its address-space with the parent. This does not necessarily die when the parent dies. To fix this, there is a "master thread" which pthreads creates. This master thread does various things, one of them is to try to ensure that all the threads get killed when the process exits (for whatever reason).

1. It does not necessarily succeed
2. If it does succeed, it is not necessarily immediate, particularly if there are a large number of threads.

So if you're using Linuxthreads, possibly not.

The other threads might not exit immediately, or indeed at all.

However, no matter what thread library you use, forked child processes will continue (they might receive the signal if they are still in the same process-group, but can freely ignore it)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was useful info.